# Polarion testing reports. What is the best way to build dashboards and live reports?

Tags: testing, documentation, polarion

Where do you find knowledge about Polarion **testing reports**?

Are you using external adviser? Documentation? Videos (find only few)

Or have you been just doing "play and learn"?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very broad question.
One of the best ways is to study some extensions from the extension portal and to study the extensions from the sdk. There is a custom widget example available in the SDK.

External consultants are, depending where you are, also a good, but more pricier alternative.
The SDK Documentation is quite good, at least ok.

A good entry is **ITrackerService** and **IWorkItem** objects. For testing you will need additional **ITestManagementService** and **ITestRun**

If you want to setup and configure the system by yourself you need to "play and learn", otherwise it is clever(but costly) to let a external consultant do the job.